# Problems in accessing sub properties from separate JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to access sub-properties from a javascript file and it's giving me something weird!

Suppose this is my JS file named **data.js**

```
module.exports = {
    something: {
        name: "Something",
        num: 1,
        email: "something@gmail.com"
    },

    somethingtwo: {
        name: "Something Something",
        num: 2,
        email: "somethingtwo@gmail.com"
    },
};
```

In my main js file named **app.js**, where I need to access it, it looks like

```
    var persons = require('./data.js');

    var getAName = function() {
    for(var name in persons) {
       console.log(name.email);
    }
}
```

I really don't know what goes wrong but I have been trying this for quite a long time now. The expected output is the email Ids from the **data.js** file but instead, i get **undefined** times the number of entries (if there are 2 entries in data.js, then I get 2 undefine and so on).

How can I access the email or the num from the **data.js** without those undefines?

`console.log(name)` is returning `something somethingtwo`

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(name)`?

Comment: @aletzo That would only return "something somethingtwo"

Comment: @aletzo yep just edited my post with that

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var name in persons) {
           //persons is actually an object not array
           //you are actually iterating through keys of an object
           //var name represent a key in that object
           console.log(persons[name]); //value corresponding to the key
}
```

I guess this code will give you the desired result.

Comment: and that's that, it worked! Can you explain please? so that i don't make these mistakes in future

Answer (score 0):

> You should be using `console.log(persons[name].email)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, `name.email` is undefined because `name` is a string.

You can test that by writing

```
console.log(typeof name);
```

Now, to solve your problem, you need to access the property correctly:

```
var getAName = function() {
    for (var name in persons) {
        console.log(persons[name].email)
    }
}
```

Returns:

> something@gmail.com 
>   somethingtwo@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

require don't automatically calls the module

```
var DataArchive = require('./data.js');
var module = DataArchive.module;
var persons = module.exports;

var getAName = function() {
for(var person in persons) {
    //person should be something (first iteration) and somethingtwo (second iteration)
   console.log(person.email);
}
```

Comment: in that case you still have to call it as a variable from the other file that is located on persons, i am gona edit my post